# $A \leqslant B$ for operators implies $\lVert{A\phi}\rVert \leqslant \lVert{B\phi}\rVert$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider two (possibly unbounded) closed operators $A, B$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, such that $\langle \phi, A \phi \rangle \leqslant \langle \phi, B \phi \rangle$ for all $\phi \in \mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{D}$ denotes the common domain of both operators.

It this enough to conclude that there exists some constant $C>0$ such that $\lVert{A \phi}\rVert \leqslant C \lVert{B \phi}\rVert$? Both operators are also lower bounded, if that helps. The scenario I am considering is one in which $B = A + A'$, where $A$ and $A'$ are non-negative, and I would like to obtain a bound of the form $\lVert{A'\phi}\rVert \leqslant (1+C)\lVert{B\phi}\rVert$.

Comment: This fails already for $A=-2Id$ and $B=Id$.

Comment: Hey daw, thanks for the comment. Its also clearly not true for $A, B$ positive, although my intuition was for something like $A = 3 Id, B = 2 Id$ so then $A^2 = 9 Id \geqslant B^2 = 4 Id$, and I was hoping for something more general than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It this enough to conclude that there exists some constant $C > 0$ such that $\| A \phi \| \leq \| B \phi \|$?

No, this is not enough to make this conclusion. Observe that by squaring both sides and expanding the squared norm via the inner product, the inequality $\| A \phi \| \leq \| B \phi \|$ is equivalent to
$$
\langle A \phi, A \phi \rangle 
\leq 
\langle B \phi, B \phi \rangle 
\quad \forall \phi \in \mathcal{D} 
\quad (\dagger)
$$
which is different from your assumption that
$$
\langle \phi, A \phi \rangle 
\leq 
\langle \phi, B \phi \rangle 
\quad \forall \phi \in \mathcal{D} . 
\quad (\ddagger)$$
In particular, to see that $(\dagger)$ does not imply $(\ddagger)$, it's enough to consider $D = \mathbb{R}^2$ and
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Functions that map operators to operators which preserve the Loewner ordering are called *operator monotone*. See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/173001) for more information.

You mentioned that you are interested in the case where $B = A + A'$. In this case, we can show that

$$
\| B \phi \|
= \| (A + A') \phi \| 
\leq \| A \phi \| + \| A' \phi \|
= 2 \| A \phi \|
\enspace ,
$$
where the inequality follows from the triangle inequality.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks very much for the link, today I have learned about Löwner ordering! Do you happen to know under which conditions $A^2 \geqslant B^2$ if $A \geqslant B$, if such a characterization exists? Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped! I don't know about some clean characterization like this, but I think that this holds if $A$ and $B$ are diagonal with positive entries. This should generalize to $A$ and $B$ simultaneously diagonalizable and positive semidefinite.